# Is it possible to parse List using Enumeration?

Tags: java, collections, enumeration

Is it possible to pass List using Enumeration?

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(1);
l.add(5);
l.add(112);

    Enumeration<Integer> e;
```

How i can get all the list into enumeration?

Thanks.

Comment: the [Java API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) says `Iterator should be preferred over Enumeration, as "Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java collections framework." ` So,why use it?Why not use `for`  loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the enumeration -

[`public static <T> Enumeration<T> enumeration(Collection<T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#enumeration%28java.util.Collection%29)

---

Also, as @Anirudh has stated in the comment, unless you are dealing with some legacy code, you should prefer the [`Iterator<E> iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(5);
    l.add(112);
    Enumeration<Integer> e = Collections.enumeration(l);
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the answer to your problem:
http://www.java-examples.com/get-enumeration-over-java-arraylist-example
It includes a complete example on how to do it.